# how postwalk form argument is parsed

Tags: clojure

```
>(use 'clojure.walk)
>(def thing {:page/tags [{:tag/category "lslsls"}]})

>(postwalk #(println %) thing)
:page/tags
:tag/category
lslsls
[nil nil]
{}
[nil]
[nil nil]
{}
=> nil
```

I am not sure why did it print out following

```
[nil nil]
{}
[nil]
[nil nil]
{}
```

since I am new to Clojure, maybe something I am missing.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: from the doc `uses f's return value in place of the original`, your f is **println** which returns **nil**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have expected

```
user=> (clojure.walk/postwalk-demo thing)
Walked: :page/tags
Walked: :tag/category
Walked: "lslsls"
Walked: [:tag/category "lslsls"]
Walked: {:tag/category "lslsls"}
Walked: [{:tag/category "lslsls"}]
Walked: [:page/tags [{:tag/category "lslsls"}]]
Walked: {:page/tags [{:tag/category "lslsls"}]}
{:page/tags [{:tag/category "lslsls"}]}
```

Since walks substitute for each subform the return value of the function used, you need return a copy of the subform after printing it, as in

```
user=> (source clojure.walk/postwalk-demo)
(defn postwalk-demo
  "Demonstrates the behavior of postwalk by printing each form as it is
  walked.  Returns form."
  {:added "1.1"}
  [form]
  (postwalk (fn [x] (print "Walked: ") (prn x) x) form))
```